# I want to store the multiple spinner checked value insert into sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

My project is attendance based. When I select the checkbox to mark attendance of students, on button click it will save on my sqlite database. but here only save one value that is last value on spinner.

How can I store multiple checkbox value of spinner into database on button click with other values?

This is my `attendancetakerclass`:

### attendancetakerclass

```
public class AttendanceTracker extends Activity {
    // ArrayList<String> NameList;
    DataBaseHelper dbHelper;
    String classcode;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Button save_attendance;
    String type2="student";
    //String type1="student";
    //RadioGroup rg;
    TextView date,time;
    static String class1;
     String type;
     String slot;
    String datetime1;
    String subject, bioid,datevalue,timevalue;
    List<Model> bioid1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.attendancetaker);

         dbHelper=new DataBaseHelper(AttendanceTracker.this);
            this.db=dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            date=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvdatetime);
            datevalue=date.getText().toString();
            time=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvtime);
            timevalue=time.getText().toString();
           String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());

         // textView is the TextView view that should display it
           date.setText(currentDateTimeString);

            Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
            today.setToNow();
            time.setText(today.format("%k:%M:%S"));
             //bioid=dbHelper.getbioid();

            Bundle extras = this.getIntent().getExtras();

            String inputfname1=extras.getString("firstn1");
            String inputlname1=extras.getString("lastn1");
            String inputclass=extras.getString("class");
            String inputsub=extras.getString("sub");
            String inputslot=extras.getString("type");
            String inputprctslot=extras.getString("slot");

            TextView viewfname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvname);
            viewfname.setText(inputfname1);
            TextView viewlname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvsurnamevalue);
            viewlname.setText(inputlname1);
            TextView viewclass = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvclassvalue);
            viewclass.setText(inputclass);
            classcode = viewclass.getText().toString();
            TextView viewsub = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvsubjectname);
            viewsub.setText(inputsub);
            subject = viewsub.getText().toString();
            TextView viewslot = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvslotvalue);
            viewslot.setText(inputslot);
            type = viewslot.getText().toString();
            TextView viewprcts = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvprctsvalue);
            viewprcts.setText(inputprctslot);
            slot = viewprcts.getText().toString();

            ListView studentList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.take_attend_list);
            bioid1=this.getbioid();
            ArrayAdapter<Model> adapter = new MyAdapter(this,getdata(),getdatalname(),getbioid());

            studentList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
public List<Model> getdata()
    {

      List<Model> list = new ArrayList<Model>();
        Cursor cursor =db.rawQuery("SELECT firstname FROM users WHERE type='"+type2+"' AND class_code='"+classcode+"'", null);
        //Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT firstname,lastname FROM attndrecords", null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do
            {
                list.add(get(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("firstname"))));
                //list.add(get(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lastname"))));
              // bioid= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("bioid"));
               //list.add(get(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("bioid"))));
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return list;

    }

public List<Model> getbioid()
{

  List<Model> list = new ArrayList<Model>();
    Cursor cursor =db.rawQuery("SELECT bioid FROM users WHERE type='"+type2+"' AND class_code='"+classcode+"'", null);
    //Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT firstname,lastname FROM attndrecords", null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {
            //list.add(get(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("firstname"))));
            //list.add(get(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lastname"))));
          // bioid= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("bioid"));
           list.add(get(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("bioid"))));
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return list;

}

private Model get(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new Model(string, string, string);
}
public List<Model> getdatalname()
{

    List<Model> listlname = new ArrayList<Model>();
    Cursor cursor =db.rawQuery("SELECT lastname FROM users WHERE type='"+type2+"' AND class_code='"+classcode+"'", null);
    //Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT firstname,lastname FROM attndrecords", null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {
            //list.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("firstname")));
            listlname.add(get(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lastname"))));
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return listlname;

}
/*public String getbioid()
{
    String query = "SELECT bioid FROM users WHERE type='" +type2+"' AND class_code='"+classcode+"'";
        Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(query, null);
       if(cursor.getCount()<0) // UserName Not Exist
       {
        cursor.close();
        return "NOT EXIST";
       }
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String bioid= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("bioid"));
        cursor.close();
        return bioid;
}*/
public void insertdata()
{
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    // Retrive Data from list
    for (Model bean : bioid1) {

        if (bean.isSelected()) {
            sb.append(bean.getBioid());
            //sb.append(",");
            Toast.makeText(this, sb.toString().trim(), 1000);
        }
    }
       String query = "INSERT INTO '"+classcode+"'(bioid,date,time,subject,slot) VALUES('"+sb+"','"+datevalue+"','"+timevalue+"','"+subject+"','"+slot+"')";
        Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(query, null);
       if(cursor.getCount()<0) // UserName Not Exist
       {
        cursor.close();
        return;
       }
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        cursor.close();
}


/*public void savedata(String bioid,String datevalue,String timevalue,String subject,String slot) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("bioid", bioid);
    values.put("date", datevalue);
    values.put("time", timevalue);
    values.put("subject", subject);
    values.put("slot", slot);
    db.insert(classcode, null, values);

    db.close();
}*/


public void submit_details(View v)
   {
    //savedata(bioid, datevalue, timevalue, subject, slot);
    insertdata();
    Toast.makeText(AttendanceTracker.this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
     alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Attendance Submitted Successfully. Please Connect the Device to WiFi");

     alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            Intent i = new Intent(AttendanceTracker.this, Attendance.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
     });

     alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
           finish();      }
     });

     AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();

   }
}
```

### My AttendancePOJO

```
package com.edbeans.attendance;

public class AttendancePOJO {

    String bioid;
    String date;
    String time;
    String subject;
    String slot;

public AttendancePOJO()
{


}
public AttendancePOJO(String bioid, String date, String time,String subject, String slot)
{
   this.bioid=bioid;
   this.date=date;
   this.time=time;
   this.subject=subject;
   this.slot=slot;
}
public String getBioid() {
    return bioid;
}
public void setBioid(String bioid) {
    this.bioid = bioid;
}
public String getDate() {
    return date;
}
public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}
public String getTime() {
    return time;
}
public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
}
public String getSubject() {
    return subject;
}
public void setSubject(String subject) {
    this.subject = subject;
}
public String getSlot() {
    return slot;
}
public void setSlot(String slot) {
    this.slot = slot;
}
}


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


## My custom adapter ##

<pre><code>package com.edbeans.attendance;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {

      private final List<Model> list;
      private final List<Model> list2;
      private final List<Model> list3;
      private final Activity context;

      public MyAdapter(Activity context, List<Model> list, List<Model> list2, List<Model> list3) {
        super(context, R.layout.attend_layout, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
        this.list2=list2;
        this.list3=list3;
      }


    static class ViewHolder {
        protected TextView text;
        protected CheckBox checkbox;


      }

      @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
          LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
          view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.attend_layout, null);
          final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
          viewHolder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvstudentfname);
          viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
          viewHolder.checkbox
              .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                  Model element = (Model) viewHolder.checkbox
                      .getTag();
                  element.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());

                }
              });
          view.setTag(viewHolder);
          viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
        } else {
          view = convertView;
          ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
        }
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        holder.text.setText(list.get(position).getName()+ " " + list2.get(position).getLname()+" " + list3.get(position).getBioid());
       // holder.text(list3.get(position));
        holder.checkbox.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());
        return view;
      }
    }
```

How can I store all checked value means bioid of all students and date time class? How can U store multiple values at a time on single button click?

Comment: Hello can anyone give me suggestion for this

Comment: I think you didn't get any replies here because (a) you marked it as urgent, which tends to put people off replying - all questions are answered by volunteers here. Also (b) it's too broad - I'm not a Java programmer, but it sounds like there's some functionality missing and you want someone to add it.  Perhaps that's a lot of work? Generally Stack Overflow is for specific, focussed technical problems. Can you narrow the problem down at all?

Comment: @halfer hey thanks.. means never tell that its urgent.. and thanks for rpl.. definitely vl follow your instruction next time..

Comment: OK. You may also wish to make the question less broad if you want help _this_ time - it's over two weeks old, and I wonder if people feel it is too broad to tackle. Can you add any further detail here e.g. further research you've done?

Comment: Ya sure.. thank u so much..